# How to noindex nofollow custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, nofollow, noindex

I've created a custom post type that displays the individual entries collectively on a page. However, I've found that Google is not only indexing the page, but the individual posts as well.

I only want the page to be indexed and followed, and not the posts. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question here:

The [WordPress SEO](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/) plugin provides a menu for all posts and pages, including custom post types, that includes noindex and nofollow options.